# Sturm-louville heat problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

Could I request for an example to the above question? I've read thru the regular sturm-liouville theory but have no idea how should the theory be applied to this problem. I understand that the method of separation of variables cannot be used (as of now) because of the existence of one of the non-homogenous boundary conditions.

If anyone could kick me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=X(x)T(t)$ apply seperation of variables, and $u$ is of the form 
$$u(x,t)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty C_ke^{-\lambda_kt}X_k(x),$$
I have used $\lambda_k$ to represent the constant in the two problems $T_k'(t)=-\lambda_k T(t)$, and $X''_k(x)=-\lambda_kX(x)$.
Now $u(x,0)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty C_kX_k(x)=f(x)$, note that the $X_k$ are eigenvalues of Laplaces equation, so integrating with $X_n$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$, and noting that distinct eigenfunctions are orthogonal, we obtain
$$\int f(x)X_n\,dx=C_n\int X_n(x)^2\,dx.$$
This gives a formula for all of the $C_n$, and thus a formula for $u$. All of the $\lambda_k$ are non negative, so the temperature distribution ($u$) goes to zero as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: Hi Ellya, could I trouble you by requesting for an explanation behind how you arrived at the u(x,t)? The boundary condition is making the question harder to solve.